# Google Cloud SQL connection is very slow

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We are using google cloud sql instace with our project and we are using Squirrel and Toad as admin tools for our instance.

In the recent days our instace performance is very slow. Connecting our cloud sql instace with the admin tool itself very slow.

In some times it not even establishes the connection with the admin tool for around 2 mins. After that only the connection get established.

We also checked with other internet connection also. In that also the performance is too low.

Can you plese check the performance of the google cloud sql.

Comment: Just to confirm. Are you connecting using Squirrel/Toad from your local computer using your Cloud SQL instance IP Address?

Comment: @JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin, In Squirrel we are using the command line configured driver. And in the Toad we are using the Cloud SQL instance IP Address.